# Spring AOP reflectionException при создании компонента

Tags: java, spring, aop

При запуске проги видает ошибку:

> черв. 09, 2017 8:00:31 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
>   INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4ccabbaa: startup date [Fri Jun 09 20:00:31 EEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   черв. 09, 2017 8:00:32 PM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext refresh
>   WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>       at Gambler.main(Gambler.java:16)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor': BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:479)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
>       at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
>       at org.steam.gambler.spring.AppContext.(AppContext.java:7)
>       ... 1 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getPointcut(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:220)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisor(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:203)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisors(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:136)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:109)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:90)
>       at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:103)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:248)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1037)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1011)
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
>       ... 10 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 20 more

Process finished with exit code 1

Вот клас конфигурации Spring(org.steam.gambler.spring.Config):

```
package org.steam.gambler.spring;

import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {
        "org.steam.gambler.steam",
        "org.steam.gambler.script",
        "org.steam.gambler.spring.logging"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ChromeDriver chromeDriver(){
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        return driver;
    }
}
```

Вот класс самого аспекта(org.steam.gambler.spring.logging.GamblingLogs):

```
    package org.steam.gambler.spring.logging;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class GamblingLogs {

    @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(org.steam.gambler.spring.annotation.Loggable)")
    public void gambleMethod(){}

    @Before("gambleMethod()")
    public void beforeGamble() {
        System.out.print("ddsadsadsa");
    }

}
```

Если в классе-аспекте убрать метод beforeGamble(), то програма запускаеться и все работает, стоит только добавить етот метод, как сразу краш проги. 
Вот структура проекта + класс с методом отмеченим аннотацией @Loggable:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**
pom.xml файл:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>site-scen</groupId>
    <artifactId>site-scen</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Selenium -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AOP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: @Pointcut(value = "@annotation(org.steam.gambler.spring.annotation.Loggable)")

Comment: И правда, тормознул. А spring-aspects в зависимостях есть?

Comment: Добавил в теле вопроса pom.xml файл. Там есть spring-aop, разве к нему еще нужно spring-aspects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить в зависимости

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Ошибка ReflectionWorldException исчезла. Но появились проблеми с компонентами контейнера. Маркую ваш ответ правильним. Спасибо.